# Can we link Confluence page to get the specflow feature file which is Azure devops repo?

Tags: azure-devops, bdd, specflow, confluence

I have confluence page, where I want to store all my feature files(specflow), so that Business can have a look. Currently these feature file resides in a repository in Azure Devops. Is there a way to dynamically link these two , so that Confluence gets updated with the latest feature files ?

Thanks,
Rajee

Comment: Looks like there's a Confluence connector for this purpose, you might want to give it a try: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1223149/azure-devops-confluence-connector?hosting=cloud&tab=overview. Although, it is not free, but there's a trial period to understand whether it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same basic problem, too. Our code is in DevOps and our product owner needs access to the feature files, but without a higher license in DevOps they cannot see repos.

1. I submit a pull request even to include new features. I mention the work item Id for the epic, story, feature or bug it pertains to in the commit message. I like to use [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) for commit messages in this case:

   > docs: Cucumber tests for X feature (related #1234)

   (where `#1234` is the work item Id in DevOps)
2. Make sure the epic, feature or story is linked to the pull request in DevOps.
3. Upon completing the pull request DevOps adds a link from the epic, feature story or bug to the pull request, providing some traceability to the real code.
4. Next, I copy and paste the feature files and scenarios into the acceptance criteria for stories, steps to reproduce for bugs or the description for features and epics. I also include a relative file path in the work item description to the feature file:

   > *(copied and pasted from Project.Specs/Foo/Bar.feature)*
   >
   > ```
   > Feature: ...
   >    In order to ...
   >    As a ...
   >    I want to ...
   >
   > Scenario: ...
   >
   > Scenario: ...
   > ```

It's a manual process, but you could adopt something similar in Confluence. You might not get the link from the commit to the wiki document, but basically copy and paste is your only free choice.

If your customers have read access to DevOps (which they should) adopting the procedure I outlined above at least gives you some traceability between the work item and a pull request that added the features to the repository. Then it is a manual step to copy and paste the features into the work item descriptions or acceptance criteria so the customers can review and approve. Annoying? Yes. But it does the trick.